# How to transfer data between two android devices?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, p2p

I was wondering what options do we have to exchange data between two different android devices?

For example, User-A and User-B both installs my app. I would like User-A to send data (possibly just a simple message or user-A's location info) to User-B.

I will be glad for any useful examples or links.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user A and B are not physically close or on the same wlan, you're going to need a server between them.  Most users are behind a NAT, so they won't be able to be sent data directly (they won't be able to open a listening socket and receive connection requests).  You pretty much have to send the data from device A to a server, then have device B poll the server (or use GCM Push).

Answer (score 0):

you can use bluetooth to send the data,

refer the following link

[How to send a text message to a paired device through bluetooth in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476835/how-to-send-a-text-message-to-a-paired-device-through-bluetooth-in-android)